# AWS S3 Presigned URL file upload - Retain file name in bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files into S3 bucket using presigned PUT URL like below

```
String tempFileKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(tempBucketName, tempFileKey)
                            .withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
                            .withExpiration(expiration);
    URL fileUrl = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

The problem with above approach is if the user uploads a file named 'xyz.jpg', I am not able to retain the file name (or extension) in the s3 bucket. The file gets saved with the tempFileKey as name. I won't be knowing the file name or extension while creating the presigned url.

I tried using ${filename} as tempFilekey as suggested in [Sending file direct from browser to S3 but changing file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386520/sending-file-direct-from-browser-to-s3-but-changing-file-name) but it is just getting saved under the name ${filename} (literally)

Comment: When you create and share a pre-signed URL, *you* dictate the object's bucket and key (nothing else would be sensible). If you want to give the client the opportunity to propose a key then have them send you that in advance, validate it, and include it in your pre-signed calculation.

Answer (score 1):

S3 can use the user-provided filename if you put `${filename}` in the signed key.

Docs are at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

Perhaps your problem is PUT vs POST?

There is a worked example here that uses this in an HTML form with `${filename}` in the `key`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Comment: Can you provide an example for this?

Comment: Amazon have published a worked example; I have added a link

Answer (score 0):

Object key is integral part of the pre-signed url and is required by the algorithm which generates the url:

- [Authenticating Requests: Using Query Parameters (AWS Signature Version 4)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html)

Thus, you **can't change** the key.

Comment: That's not completely true -- AWS have added special handling to allow the user supplied filename to be used, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html